# Get-ADGroupMembers with User account Enabled status

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to return a CSV of all security groups in my domain and all members including their account status (enabled or disabled) but can't seem to work out how to get join from ADGroupMember to ADUser. Was trying to test for value of `$Member.ObjectClass` and if "user" then run `Get-ADUser` but this doesn't seem to work - all ADGroupMember object classes appear as user if I do that. If possible would like to do it in one query. I've taken an example from the web and tried to modify it without success.

I'm looking for results in a table/csv formatted like this:

[image: Screenshot for formatting]

```
GroupName    Name        ObjectClass     Enabled
GroupA       John Smith  User            True 
GroupB       Jane Brown  User            False 
GroupB       GroupN      Group           NA/Group
```

---

```
$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{
    "GroupName" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "ObjectClass" = ""
    "Enabled" = ""
}

$Groups = Get-AdGroup -Filter * |
          Where {$_.Name -like "FS01*" -or $_.Name -like "ABC*"} |
          Select Name -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $ArrayMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                    Select Name, ObjectClass #, SamAccountName

    foreach ($Member in $ArrayMembers) {
        $Record."Enabled" = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                            Get-ADUser |
                            Select Enabled 
        $Record."GroupName" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.Name
        $Record."ObjectClass" = $Member.ObjectClass

        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
        $Table += $objRecord
    }
}
$Table # | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: so what doesn't work? I don't have an AD domain to test it, but this looks "sound"

Comment: There were a few things not working. First off 3 of the groups were returning errors when using Get-ADGroupMember. I suspect this was because the group display name was different to the SAM account name. Secondly the list would display okay (except for the 3 errors mentioned above) when NOT attempting to check the ObjectClass of the the member however as soon as I put in an if then statement to check for user or group and run Get-ADUser if ObjectClass was user it would display only user as the ObjectType for all rows. Couldn't get the if then to work properly.

Comment: Would be interested to get the original working for learning purposes unless this is deemed a ridiculous way to go about it. Ansgar's example certainly seems more concise and will use it going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. Use `Select-Object` to select name and object class from the group members, and inject group name and enabled status via [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -like 'FS01*' -or
  $_.Name -like 'ABC*'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $groupname = $_.Name
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ |
    Select-Object @{n='GroupName';e={$groupname}}, Name, ObjectClass,
                  @{n='Enabled';e={if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
                    Get-ADUser $_ | Select-Object -Expand Enabled
                  } else {
                    'NA/Group'
                  }}}
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar! Your example works brilliantly. Your example seems more complicated to me because I've not seen the "Select-Object @{n='GroupName';e={$groupname}}" (the n= and e=) before but I'm absolutely not a PS expert (obviously). I will do some reading about how it works. There is one brace too many on the end before the last pipe though for anyone watching at home.

Comment: @Scott `n` is short for `Name`, `e` is short for `Expression`. For further explanation please see the link in my answer.